# strpos() within while loop never ends

Tags: php, while-loop, strpos

There's a string,

> $string = 'Foo, Bar, Test,';

**All I want to do is to count the number of the commas within a string.**

But everything leads to infinite while loop.

So, I've tried #1:

$count = 0;

```
while($pos = strpos($string, ',') !== FALSE){
    $count++;
    // Never ends
}
```

And also #2,

```
while(true){
  if ( strpos($string, ',') !== FALSE ){
     $count++;
  } else {
    break;
  }
}
```

**They both never end. Where's the problem?**

Comment: `strpos()` doesn't alter `$string`. You'll get the same result each iteration.

Comment: I know it doesn't answer your question but this might be one of those "asking the wrong question" situations. Both Prasanth and Jack have offered you the "best" way to count these commas and you really should use their suggested methods for such things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just use `substr_count()`:

```
substr_count($string, ',');
```

In your code, `strpos()` requires a third parameter to start searching from a particular offset, e.g.:

```
strpos($string, ',', 12); // start searching from index 12
```

It doesn't work like an iterator. Something like this would work:

```
$start = 0;
while (($pos = strpos($string, ',', $start)) !== FALSE) {
  $count++;
  $start = $pos + 1;
}
```

**Update**

If you want to get real fancy:

```
class IndexOfIterator implements Iterator
{
  private $haystack;
  private $needle;

  private $start;
  private $pos;
  private $len;
  private $key;

  public function __construct($haystack, $needle, $start = 0)
  {
    $this->haystack = $haystack;
    $this->needle = $needle;
    $this->start = $start;
  }

  public function rewind()
  {
    $this->search($this->start);
    $this->key = 0;
  }

  public function valid()
  {
    return $this->pos !== false;
  }

  public function next()
  {
    $this->search($this->pos + 1);
    ++$this->key;
  }

  public function current()
  {
    return $this->pos;
  }

  public function key()
  {
    return $this->key;
  }

  private function search($pos)
  {
    $this->pos = strpos($this->haystack, $this->needle, $pos);
  }
}

foreach (new IndexOfIterator($string, ',') as $match) {
  var_dump($match);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[`strpos()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) returns the first occurrence of the `$needle`, so unless you specify different `$offset`, you'll always get the same result, thus the endless loop.

If you insist on using `strpos()`, try this:

```
$pos=0;
while(($pos = strpos($string, ',',$pos)) !== FALSE){
    $count++;
    $pos++;
    // This ends
}
```

Off course you can use [`substr_count()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) to make things easier.

**Edit**:

[Live demo](http://3v4l.org/LKlCd)

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
$text = 'Foo, Bar, Test,';
echo substr_count($text, ',');
```

ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php

Answer (score 0):

Or try this if substr_count not fit:

```
$pos = -1;
$count=0;
while( $pos = strpos($in, ',', $pos+1) !== FALSE){
     $count++;
     }
```

I didn't test whether you absolutely need !==FALSE. If you use mb_strpos you don't.